# How can I disable the Maven Javadoc plugin from the command line?

Tags: java, maven, command-line, command-line-arguments, maven-javadoc-plugin

In `pom.xml` I have declaration like this

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

is there any way to turn that off from command line?

I do know I can extract that into a profile, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 559, accepted):

The Javadoc generation can be skipped by setting the property `maven.javadoc.skip` to `true` [[1](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#skip)], i.e.

```
-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

(and not `false`)

Comment: See @Christoph-Tobias Schenke answer for approach to take with child modules.

Comment: This argument can also be set directly in jenkins to avoid this problem (in Global MAVEN_OPTS defined in Configure System)

Comment: This didn't work for me, but learned that when you use the maven release plugin you need to pass this parameter differently.  This worked:
```mvn release:perform -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"```.

Answer (score 234):

It seems, that the simple way

```
-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

does not work with the release-plugin. in this case you have to pass the parameter as an "argument"

```
mvn release:perform -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"
```

Comment: If you need to add two arguments you can separate them with a space like this `-Darguments="-DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"`

Comment: It also works to add these to the release plugin config in the root-level pom.xml: `<configuration><arguments>-DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true</arguments></configuration>`

Comment: In addition, skipTests comes in a stronger flavor that also skips compilation of tests: `-Dmaven.tests.skip=true`

Comment: Wow, why does the maven release plugin do this...totally lost some time on this one

Comment: somehow this didn't work for me

Answer (score 146):

You can use the [`maven.javadoc.skip`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/javadoc/AbstractJavadocMojo.html#skip) property to skip execution of the plugin, going by the Mojo's javadoc. You can specify the value as a Maven property:

```
<properties>
    <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
</properties>
```

or as a command-line argument: `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`, to skip generation of the Javadocs.

Comment: This answer doesnt really answer the question, since in there it states that the switch should be done via the command line.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for a multi-module project with a few modules not generating any javadoc and causing an error otherwise.

Answer (score 25):

Add to the release plugin config in the root-level pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <arguments>-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true</arguments>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this is not properly from command line as required by the question, but it works great if you need to disable permanently the javadoc.

Answer (score 5):

Dans le pom.xml

1st option : using properties

```
<properties>
    <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip> 
</properties>
```

2nd option : using the build > pluginManagement > plugins > plugin > configuration

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goals>deploy</goals>
                    <arguments>-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

3rd option : When invoking mvn (this one did not work for me)

```
 mvn clean install -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

Answer (score 3):

For newbie Powershell users it is important to know that '.' is  a syntactic element of Powershell, so the switch has to be enclosed in double quotes:

mvn clean install "-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"

Comment: Thanks for that. I was looking for this, to setup VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing is:
if you set `<skip>false<skip>` in configuration of maven-javadoc-plugin in pom.xml, the `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true` will not work, at least for maven-daemon(aka mvndaemon or mvnd).