# How do you disable the maven-assembly-plugin plugin from the command line?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

This is just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412016/how-can-i-disable-the-maven-javadoc-plugin-from-the-command-line) only this is about the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/plugin-info.html), not the javadoc plugin.  I don't want to use a profile to do this because that would be more error prone than a command line option.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I figured this out on my own.  You do it with `-Dassembly.skipAssembly=true`