# How to skip javadoc for all modules?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I need to skip generating javadoc while making a release with `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true` but this does not make skipping javadocs for submodules.
Is there a way to skip javadoc for all modules ?
Note that I can't update the pom file (not my right).
Is there a way to do it with the command line ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as you could see in the source code. The best thing that you can do is either ask the owner to introduce a maven profile for that and for you or you can do it in the dirty way: copy the pom.xml to somewhere, edit it and call the maven with

mvn -f [other pom file]

Update: Maybe I was wrong. Please check [How can I disable the Maven Javadoc plugin from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412016/how-can-i-disable-the-maven-javadoc-plugin-from-the-command-line)

Comment: As you can see as comment in the right answer : Not working for child modules. And I said that I'm already using -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true

Comment: On the link there was a (n in theory) working answer: mvn release:perform -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"

Comment: In this case, I would do it the quick and dirty way as I wrote.