# How to delete a file while doing maven install (build) from target directory

Tags: java, maven

I am looking to delete a folder (api-docs) from the target folder. When I do maven build, when the target folder is generated, it should exclude that folder(api-docs). 
 Target contains Classes, codegen, generated-sources, javadoc-bundle-options, maven-archiver, maven-status, test-classes and a war file. 
 I need to exclude(api-docs) which is present in codegen 
 Codegen > generated-sources> web> api-docs( contains css, fonts, images, lang, lib, specs and some other js and html files)

```
 <plugin>
                         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>build</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>                                  
                                    <tasks>
                                        <delete>
                                          <fileset> dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/target/codegen/generated-sources/web/api-docs"/>
                                        </delete>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>  
          `
```

I added that in pom.xml, but couldn't able to delete. Please suggest
Here is the entire contents of build from pom file

```
<build> 
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>com.xxx.chassis.api.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${codegen.plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>generate</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<templateDir>chassis-archetypes</templateDir>
<configFile>${project.parent.basedir}/codegen-config.yaml</configFile>
<specifications>
<specification>${project.parent.basedir}/partnerships-originations-product-offer-id.yaml</specification>
</specifications>
<basePackage>com.xxx.papi.popoi</basePackage>
</configuration>
</plugin> 

           <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>build</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>                                  
                                <tasks>
                                    <delete>
                                      <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/codegen/generated-sources/web/api-docs/swagger-ui.min.js"/>
                                    </delete>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>  

<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>add-source</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>add-source</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<sources>
<source>${codegen.generated-sources}/java</source>
</sources>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<sourcepath>${codegen.generated-sources}/java</sourcepath>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: If you need to use build-helper-maven-plugin the plugin `codegen-maven-plugin ` is wrongly implemented....

Answer (score 0):

Please share the entire contents of the build->plugins section of your pom file. It should not be necessary to add the maven-antrun-plugin to your pom. The apidocs folder in your target directory is usually produced by the maven-javadoc-plugin which you possibly have present in your pom file. The first way to prevent the creation of the apidocs folder would be to remove that plugin declaration from your pom. An alternative way would be to supply the maven.javadoc.skip argument as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9360317/7810853

Answer (score 0):

The goal for the [antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html) is `run`, not `build`. Changing the pom.xml accordingly should help:

```xml
[...]
<goals>
  <goal>run</goal>
</goals>
[...]
```

You also should double check in which [phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) the api-doc folder is created and you should call the ant-plugin in a later phase, for example `package`:

```xml
[...]
<phase>package</phase>
[...]
```

As a third point, the Maven variable `${project.build.outputDirectory}` usually references the folder `target/classes`. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356378/2129801) for more details. Therfore, you could either use

```xml
<fileset dir="${project.basedir}/target/codegen/generated-sources/web/api-docs"/>
```

or - more precise -

```xml
<fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/codegen/generated-sources/web/api-docs"/>
```

Comment: In the above code, I have changed goal to run and fileset to dir="${project.build.directory}/codegen/generated-sources/web/api-docs/swagger-ui.min.js"/>   <br> still unable to delete the folder/file swagger-ui.min.js

Comment: Could you please check if the ant plugin has been called? Maybe you could post your latest version of the pom.xml and the complete output when you run your build (on pastebin for example)?